# Proposed by Anonymous

Tags: discussion, questions, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

When reviewing question or answer edits, I see edits being made with the label of "Proposed by Anonymous".  How does an anonymous user make an edit to a question in Stackoverflow?

Comment: From "How do suggested edits work?": *Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 10 minutes old. These edits are attributed to the Community user.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way anyone under 2k rep makes a suggested edit; by clicking on the `edit` link under the post (albeit that it's called `improve this question` when visiting the site when not logged in).

Anonymous visitors are allowed to suggest edits on posts that are at least 10 minutes old.

Answer (score 3):

Unregistered get `improve this question` or `improve this answer` link instead of `edit`.
And as Martjin Pieters they can suggest edit same way anyone under 2k rep makes.

Test test this open any (atleast 10 minutes old) Stack Overflow question in private browsing or incognito window. You will see there `improve this...` link instead of `edit`.

And yes if their suggested edit get approved, that edit is shown as edited by [Community ♦ Moderator user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: Not *any Stack Overflow question*. Any question *at least 10 minutes old*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yes. I tested it right now.